# Joda Invalid format exception

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to convert a string from to a Joda DateTime object.  The date is coming from a SQLlite datefield, eg:

```
 2011-11-19 18:29:41
```

The code I'm using is:

```
 DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime("2011-11-19 18:29:41").withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
```

but I'm getting this exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2011-11-19 18:29:41" is malformed at "11-11-19 18:29:41"
```

EDIT: here is more details in what I'm doing:

I have a utility class, which has a method I'm using to convert strings to DateTime:

```
public static DateTime GetItemDate(final String date, String pattern)
{
    return DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).parseDateTime(date).withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
}
```

Then I call:

```
 Utilities.GetItemDate("2011-11-19 18:29:41", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: The code you've given works for me. Could you post a short but complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Added some more details to the OP.

Comment: It's still working for me. I've posted a short but complete program which *does* work with both of the sample patterns you've given. Can you post a similar short but complete example which *doesn't* work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the patterns you've given actually work for me (I've taken the liberty of making the method name follow Java naming conventions, but the body is the same).

It's worth nothing that the patterns *are* different though - "y" is "year" (which could be negative) whereas "Y" is "year of era".

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Works
        DateTime dateTime = getItemDate("2011-11-19 18:29:41",
                                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println(dateTime);

        // Works for me too...
        dateTime = getItemDate("2011-11-19 18:29:41",
                               "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }

    public static DateTime getItemDate(String date, String pattern) {
        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)
            .parseDateTime(date)
                .withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    }
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
2011-11-19T18:29:41.000Z
2011-11-19T18:29:41.000Z
```

I'd actually suggest that you specify the time zone for the *formatter* too - as otherwise it's going to use the default time zone already.

What locale are you in? Perhaps that's causing a problem...

Comment: OK, maybe there is something else I'm doing wrong. This is being used in an Android project, if that makes any difference.  My locale is EST.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was getting the error in a different part of the code where I was passing in the parameter: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a.  Thanks for your help though, it forced me to look at other parts of my project for the issue.